# Page display with URL Rewrite on Amazon Elastic Load Balancer (URL rewrite works but the page doesn't display)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, amazon-web-services, nginx

There is an issue with Page display with URL rewriting when the ELB handles the request. I have been using 2 instances and load balancer automatically processes the request using one of the instances. When I browse using the Public IP of any of the 2 instances independently, the URL rewriting works fine and page is rendered as expected. But, when I browse using the load balanced URL, the URL rewrite works but the page doesn't work and throws 404 error.

FYI, I have been using apache as web server on instance 1 and nginx as web server on instance 2. I think there shouldn't be a problem because of this.

Please suggest.

Comment: It "doesn't work" is not usually a helpful description of a problem.  What is the expected behavior, what is the observed behavior, what have you configured in config files, and how can we replicate your problem?  You "think there shouldn't be" an nginx vs apache problem? What happens when you remove one or the other server from ELB, but still access it via ELB?  If you haven't tried that, then you have no justification to "think there shouldn't be a problem" related to it.

Comment: The URL rewriting works fine when accessed directly and when browsed with ELB, the rewrite works but the page cannot be displayed i.e., 404 error. I tried removing one from ELB, then the page works fine with apache. There is a problem with the page display (404 error) on the server with nginx.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve the issue. The problem is in the virtual host configuration of one instance with apache wherein the Public IP is specified. When I used the ELB address instead of Public IP, the issue is fixed.